Svg to Jsx wrapped in react component
I'm working on a project where i need to convert a svg image accessed from the user's computer to a jsx wrapped react component.First i need to check whether the conversion is taking place correctly or not.So i created a demo code where i initialised  the svg code to be converted as a variable and passed it as an argument to the transform function from @svgr/core library but i found that the svg image is getting converted partially with svgoparseerror.I mean i can see the partially transformed react component in the console.
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const outputFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'output.js');

const svgContent = `<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  </svg>
`;

try {
  // Transform the SVG string into JSX
  const result = transform.sync(svgContent, {
    plugins: [
      '@svgr/plugin-jsx',
      '@svgr/plugin-svgo',
      '@svgr/plugin-prettier'
    ],
    // Specify @babel/preset-react as a preset
    babel: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
    },
  });

  // Write the transformed JSX code to a file
  fs.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, result, 'utf8');
  console.log('Transform successful!');
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Transform error:', err);
}

    at sax.onerror (/Users/yugdev/Documents/SVG /server/node_modules/svgo/lib/parser.js:247:19)
    at emit (/Users/yugdev/Documents/SVG /server/node_modules/@trysound/sax/lib/sax.js:518:35)
    at error (/Users/yugdev/Documents/SVG /server/node_modules/@trysound/sax/lib/sax.js:549:5)
    at strictFail (/Users/yugdev/Documents/SVG /server/node_modules/@trysound/sax/lib/sax.js:573:7)
    at beginWhiteSpace (/Users/yugdev/Documents/SVG /server/node_modules/@trysound/sax/lib/sax.js:847:7)
    at SAXParser.write (/Users/yugdev/Documents/SVG /server/node_modules/@trysound/sax/lib/sax.js:902:11)
    at parseSvg (/Users/yugdev/Documents/SVG /server/node_modules/svgo/lib/parser.js:259:7)
    at optimize (/Users/yugdev/Documents/SVG /server/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo.js:66:17)
    at Object.optimize (/Users/yugdev/Documents/SVG /server/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo-node.js:76:10)
    at svgoPlugin (/Users/yugdev/Documents/SVG /server/node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo/dist/index.js:76:23)
    at run (/Users/yugdev/Documents/SVG /server/node_modules/@svgr/core/dist/index.js:174:16)
    at transform.sync (/Users/yugdev/Documents/SVG /server/node_modules/@svgr/core/dist/index.js:184:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yugdev/Documents/SVG /server/transform.js:14:28)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1434:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1518:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1249:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:158:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:30:49 {
  reason: 'Non-whitespace before first tag.',
  line: 1,
  column: 1,
  source: 'import * as React from "react";\n' +
    'const SvgComponent = props => <svg width={100} height={100} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" {...props}><circle cx={50} cy={50} r={40} stroke="black" strokeWidth={3} fill="red" /></svg>;\n' +
    'export default SvgComponent;'
}```


i checked for any non-whitespace before first tag in the svg file im trying to convert,but found nothing.




I tried using many libraries and ended up using the @svgr/core in node.js.But its not working.I need the converted react component to make edits to the svg image.Do any of you know how to do this?


From the error output it sounds like the SVG is not a valid XML document. Try to validate the SVG and/or test with another SVG.

It seems like the SVGO plugin must be the first plugin in the array. That putting @svgr/plugin-svgo at the very first will fix your issue:
const result = transform.sync(svgContent, {
  plugins: [
    '@svgr/plugin-svgo', /* NOTE: SVGO must come first */
    '@svgr/plugin-jsx',
    '@svgr/plugin-prettier'
  ],
  babel: {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
  },
});

